# Converting system errors into friendly messages

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I want to know if there is a good way to convert system generated errors into something more meaningful for the user. for example if for some reason the application could not connect to the SMTP server. I want to convert the message thrown by the system which will be something like "SMTP connection failure" to "We could not send you an email". This friendly message I want to pull out from a resource file. While this is an example of one such exception, there could be more.

We dont have try catch blocks across all the layers. It is present only in the UI layer. We have a exception management class that takes in all exceptions and returns a friendly string from it. Every catch block in the UI layer makes a call to this exception management class and passes it an exception of type System.Exception whose method needs to return the said friendly error string for use on the UI.

The only way I can think of doing this now is having one large IF ELSE block in the exception management class that checks the exception string received and pulls out a matching friendly message from the resource file.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: IMO, that's a good approach. A resource file or a database table, in short there's a placeholder where you have a mapping of error codes or too-technical-error-messaages against your own custom-friendly-messages. And for unmapped messages, you can give users a generic friendly message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is why you have `try` `catch` to catch the exceptions. just use it with specific error types not the generic error type. so then you can display any message inside the `catch` block. but rethrowing the custom exception inside `catch` block is not recommended. In your case you can catch the `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException`

Comment: we have a exception management class that takes in all exceptions and returns a friendly string from it. Every catch block makes a call to this exception management class whose method returns the said friendly error string for use on the UI.

Comment: Don't make that exception management class's friendly message depends on the exception text.instead try to use exception type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can map an exception to a user friendly error. The reason is that an exception is "what" happened, at quite a low level, while the user only wants to know "why" that happened and what they can do to fix it. Mapping `FileNotFound` to "The system attempted to access a file which doesn't exist" will not help. Instead, catching a `FileNotFound` and then, depending on the state of the application, displaying a relevant message - will.

Another idea is to have a different error message for each process which might fail and display that error message for any exception thrown during that process. If you fine-grain your processes and your try-catching, you'll be able to provide a much better notification system to the user than if you map system error messages to user understandable error messages.